# Registrar NS records not pointing to Route 53

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-ip, ns-record

I'm having difficulty setting up Route 53 and my registrar settings. I've purchased the domain from InMotion Hosting. On the AWS side, I have my AMI set up with an Elastic IP. I successfully view the landing page (/var/www/html/index.html) when I type the Elastic IP in the browser.

I've set up a Hosted Zone and I see the two auto-created record sets for NS and for SOA. I've also created an A type record set with name of www.example.com and value set to the Elastic IP.

On the registrar site, I can edit what they call the delegation details. There are fields for primary and secondary, set to ns1.inmotionhosting.com and ns2.inmotionhosting.com. Below that are 3 empty inputs, each labeled 'Name Server'. Route 53 provides 4 NS values, so I'm not sure if I delete what's called Primary and Secondary, and use the 4 AWS values and have a leftover NS slot remaining? Or do I keep the default primary/secondary (nsX.inmotionhosting.com) and only use 3 AWS NS values?

Currently I have it set to the latter. When I visit www.example.com, I get a page that says Not Found: The requested URL / was not found on this server. When I visit http://example.com, I get an error that example.com's server DNS address could not be found.

After reading around a bit, I added a directory at /var/www/mysite.com/html and also public_html, putting an index and setting permissions in both. 
Now when I visit www.example.com, I get the AMI test page (not my index.html). When I visit http://example.com, I am redirected to a page by InMotion saying the website is unavailable. All the while, visiting the Elastic IP in the browser serves me the expected page at /var/www/html/index.

I also understand I may need to add an alias record set to have the example.com A record point to the www.example.com A record, but I believe I need to get www.example.com working first.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or do I keep the default primary/secondary (nsX.inmotionhosting.com)
>   and only use 3 AWS NS values?

No, remove whatever is there by default and populate your domain nameservers with the NS records for your R53 hosted zone.

Comment: Thanks. I used 4 of the 5 spaces with the R53 NS values, and left the other space blank. As far as the default pages, I added an index in /var/www/example.com/ and it's being loaded ok. However, when I go to the Elastic IP, it display the index in /var/www/html/. Is it ok that these aren't the same, or is there a way to have them load the same page (without something like a symlink)? Presumably the site will only be accessed through the domain name, and not the IP, but I want to make sure everything checks out.

Comment: That's a completely separate topic, so I'd recommend that you post a separate question.